# Change Default time interval to 2 hours (from 30 minutes) in SharePoint oob Calendar events

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I have an OOB SharePoint Calendar that I schedule events in.  I am constantly messing up my events because they ALWAYS take 2 hours and I forget to change the default from 30 minutes.  How can I change this default event interval?  powershell script appreciated if cannot be done via UI.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you edit the NewForm.aspx. It quite complicated, but when you're done you don't need to script any further:

> ## Editing NewForm.aspx
>
> When adding a new record to the Calendar SharePoint uses NewForm.aspx so what about modifying that?
>
> - Click “New” in your Calendar to open up NewForm.asxp
> - Add &ToolPaneView=2 onto the end of the URL to use a neat workaround to open up the list form in edit mode.
> - Add a Content Editor Web Part to the page
> - Click Open the toolpane or Edit > Modify Share Web Part
> - Click Source Editor and paste in the following JavaScript

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
  // Set the hours to add - can be over 24
  var hoursToAdd = 2;
  // Mins must be 0 or div by 5, e.g. 0, 5, 10, 15 ...
  var minutesToAdd = 0;
 
  // JavaScript assumes dates in US format (MM/DD/YYYY)
  // Set to true to use dates in format DD/MM/YYYY
  var bUseDDMMYYYYformat = false;
 
  $(function() {
 
    // Find the start and end time/minutes dropdowns by first finding the
    // labels then using the for attribute to find the id's
    // NOTE - You will have to change this if your form uses non-standard
    // labels and/or non-english language packs
    var cboStartHours = $("#" + $("label:contains('Start Time Hours')").attr("for"));
    var cboEndHours = $("#" + $("label:contains('End Time Hours')").attr("for"));
    var cboEndMinutes = $("#" + $("label:contains('End Time Minutes')").attr("for"));
 
    // Set Hour
    var endHour = cboStartHours.attr("selectedIndex") + hoursToAdd;
    cboEndHours.attr("selectedIndex",endHour % 24);
 
    // If we have gone over the end of a day then change date
    if ((endHour / 24)>=1)
    {
        var txtEndDate = $("input[title='End Time']");
        var dtEndDate = dtParseDate(txtEndDate.val());
        if (!isNaN(dtEndDate))
        {
            dtEndDate.setDate( dtEndDate.getDate() + (endHour / 24));
            txtEndDate.val(formatDate(dtEndDate));
        }
    }
 
    // Setting minutes is easy!
    cboEndMinutes.val(minutesToAdd);
 
});
 
// Some utility functions for parsing and formatting - could use a library
// such as www.datejs.com instead of this
function dtParseDate(sDate)
{
    if (bUseDDMMYYYYformat)
    {
        var A = sDate.split(/[\\\/]/);
        A = [A[1],A[0],A[2]];
        return new Date(A.join('/'));
    }
    else
        return new Date(sDate);
}
 
function formatDate(dtDate)
{
    if (bUseDDMMYYYYformat)
        return dtDate.getDate() + "/" + dtDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dtDate.getFullYear();
    else
        return dtDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dtDate.getDate() + "/" + dtDate.getFullYear();
}
 
</script>
```

Reference: [Setting a default duration for new SharePoint Calender Events](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/09/setting-default-duration-for-new-calender-events/)